# JsonResult, ActionResult, Json, DataContractJson serializer... purpose differences?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

So Im getting same results whether I use ActionResult or JsonResult in the return type.  Whats the difference and when would you use the datacontractJson serializer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JsonResult` is a class that inherits `ActionResult`.
It doesn't matter which one you declare your method as returning.

The `Json()` method is a helper method that returns a `JsonResult`; it's simpler than writing `new JsonResult { ... }`.

`JsonResult` wraps the built-in JSON serializer; it's much simpler than manually serializing your objects and writing the JSON to the response stream (that's what `JsonResult` does for you)